# Calculate average value using the average value from row above - power query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I need to calculate the flow of diesel consumption of a fleet through the average purchase value.
With each diesel purchase, I need to determine the amount of diesel in stock, the stock value and the average value of the liter (stock value divided by quantity of liter in stock).

In excel I can do it easily using the cell of row above, but in power query I can't evaluate row by row, only the entiry column.

Is there any way to do this at Power Query?

EDIT: input tables:

in:
[image]

Out:
[image]

Output desired:
[image]

Outpud desired with formulas:
[image]

Comment: Edit your question to provide a sample input table and desired output table (with obvious methodology) for powerquery and someone will help you

Comment: Is there a timestamp? Without one, how will we know if the two `11/10/2023` last rows of `Out` are before or after the last row of `In`?

Comment: I assume that In are always before Out if both are on same day

Comment: Thanks, and in the `Out` table, when the are multiple rows of the same date, does the order matter? Asking as to see if we can safely sort by date, or not.

Comment: No. The Out can be in any order if they are at the same date

Answer (score 0):

Code for Table2

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
OtherTable= Table.AddColumn(Table1, "Flow", each "In"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Reference", type date}, {"Liters Used", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Flow", each "Out"),
combined = Table.Combine({#"Added Custom",OtherTable}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(combined,null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Liters Used", "Amount"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Replaced Value",{{"Reference", Order.Ascending}, {"Flow", Order.Ascending}, {"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Sorted Rows",{"Liter Value"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Total Value", each [Liter Value]* (-[Liters Used] + [Amount])),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Index2", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "InOut", each [Amount]-[Liters Used]),
#"Added Cum Total" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Stock", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Custom2"[InOut],[Index2]+1))),
#"Added Cum Total2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Cum Total", "Stock Value", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Cum Total"[Total Value],[Index2]+1))),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Cum Total2", "Average Value", each [Stock Value]/[Stock]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Index", "Index2"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: My output appears to match your desired output

Comment: It's almost there.
I need to calculate Total Value based on Average Value, and the Average Value have to be calculated on every row.
I can't use the Liter Value to calculate the Total Value, only on first "In" row.
i.e: On first row, Average Value = Liter Value. 
From second row on, the Average Value must be the ((Average Value from row above * "InOut") + Stock Value from row above ) divided by "Stock".
And with this new Average Value, I need to calculate the Total Value

Comment: From second "In" value on, the Stock Value is slightly different because I'm using the Average value to calculate it

Comment: Provide the sample data output with the real numbers to check against. Editing code for potential answer but I want something to match against since the first code matched but was not satisfactory

Comment: If the answer has helped unblock you - then please help Accept the answer for the benefit of all.